# polar form of a double integral

Tags: calculus

given the following region $R=\lbrace m,n \geq0$, $1 \geq m+n \geq 2\rbrace$ where $(m,n) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.write in polar coordinates $(r, \theta)$ the following double integral $\int\int_R m \,dA$

Comment: my answer was $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ $\displaystyle\int_{\frac{1}{(cos \theta+ sin\theta)}^{\frac{2}{(cos \theta+ sin\theta)}}}$ $r^2$ cos $\theta$ dr d$\theta$. Is this answer true?

Comment: Yes. You are correct. $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{\frac{1}{\cos\theta + \sin\theta}}^{\frac{2}{\cos\theta +\sin\theta}}r^2\cos\theta drd\theta$.